# How to make dynamically change its width according to data from array

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So, I have three divs .inner which fills the outer div (a barlike chart if you want), and a target which represents a dotted line. I fetch two datas from an array:
$target = $data->data[2][32][3];

Which is 9.83% in this case. 
and the inner div data is:

```
$clicks = $data->data[1][32][3];
```

Which is 7.15% in this case.
So I've set the target to width 100% in the outer div.
I am trying to make the .inner div procentually fill the outer div up until it reaches the target. 
CSS:
CSS:

```
.outer,
.inner,
.target {
  height: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.outer {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.inner {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: right;
  width: calc(80% / 100 * <?php $clicks ?>);
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
.inner:after {
  content: '<?php echo number_format((float)$clicks, 2, '.', ''); ?>%';
  display: inline-block;
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  top: -14px;
}
.target {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
  border-right: 2px dotted black;
}
.target:after {
  content: 'Target: <?php echo number_format((float)$target, 2, '.', ''); ?>%';
  display: inline-block;
  left: 28px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  top: 14px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer" style="width: "<?php echo $base; ?>"> 
    <div class="target" style="width: 80%">
    </div>                   
    <div class="inner" style=" width: calc(<?php echo $bar_width; ?> / 100 * (<?php echo $clicks; ?> / <?php echo $base; ?> * 100))">
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $target = $data->data[2][32][3];
    $bar_width = '80%'; 
    $clicks = $data->data[1][32][3];
    $base   = max($target, $clicks);

?>
```

I've attached some images of how it should look like:
[image]

The problem is that I try to make the target dynamically go backwards on the outer div when the inner exceeded it .inner > .target. Any ideas on how should I accomplish this?

Comment: Don't understand based on images and description....both are confusing. Perhaps some labels on image would help.

Comment: I have added some labels

Comment: Still don't understand the target moving backwards. By what percentage? What real world use case example would this relate too? Can we think of fund raising and second image shows target was exceeded?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's the idea.

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/fqv6moqz/

Answer (score 0):

My thinking is you can set the `css right` of target when goal is exceeded using the following

```
overPercent =  ((100 * current / goal) -100)/2;
```

[Demo Using jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/fqv6moqz/)

Note: very early morning right now and my math may need a bit of refining